# Microphone Problems

Tags: linux-mint, audio, pulseaudio, microphone, alsamixer

I can't get a webcam microphone to work; it appears grayed out in Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon:

```
> System: Host: me-Peppy Kernel: 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64
> compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 wm: muffin dm: LightDM
> Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic Machine:
> Type: Desktop System: Acer product: Peppy v: 1.0 serial: Chassis:
> type: 3 serial: Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A BIOS: coreboot v: N/A
> date: 03/02/2017 Battery: ID-1: BAT0 charge: 35.9 Wh condition:
> 43.8/45.1 Wh (97%) volts: 11.9/11.2 model: SANYO AP13J3K serial: status: Discharging CPU: Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron
> 2955U bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Haswell rev: 1 L2 cache: 2048 KiB
> flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 5587
> Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/1400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798
> Graphics: Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Acer
> Incorporated ALI driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID:
> 8086:0a06 Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting
> unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz OpenGL: renderer: Mesa
> DRI Intel Haswell Mobile v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 compat-v: 3.0 direct
> render: Yes Audio: Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Acer
> Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:03.0 chip
> ID: 8086:0a0c Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Acer
> Incorporated ALI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 chip
> ID: 8086:9c20 Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-46-generic Network:
> Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9462 Wireless Network Adapter vendor:
> Foxconn driver: ath9k v: kernel port: 0400 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID:
> 168c:0034 IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: Drives: Local Storage: total:
> 119.24 GiB used: 23.44 GiB (19.7%) ID-1: /dev/sda model: NT-128 size: 119.24 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial: Partition: ID-1: / size: 114.25 GiB used: 22.96 GiB (20.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/dm-1 ID-2: /boot size:
> 703.5 MiB used: 453.0 MiB (64.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 ID-3: swap-1 size: 1.94 GiB used: 41.5 MiB (2.1%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-2 Sensors:
> System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C mobo: N/A Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A Info:
> Processes: 193 Uptime: 21m Memory: 1.82 GiB used: 1.14 GiB (62.6%)
> Init: systemd v: 237 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.5.0 alt: 7 Client:
> Unknown python3.6 client inxi: 3.0.32
```

Being the latest version of Mint and an old (and great) ACERC720. I'm suprised I'm still getting sound issues.

I couldnt't get the webcam microphone to work as the microphone was greyed out and there were no extra properties available to toggle in Alsa Mixer. So reading another forum I installed Pavucontrol.

I managed to get the microphone working for Skype\Microsoft Teams if I do the following each time I load the computer

```
Change the input, "internal microphone" to 'microphone unplugged' for Port on Input Devices
In recording tab change ""Built in Analogue Stereo" to "Monitor of Built in Analogue Stereo"
```

It's just so irritating having to change these each time before meetings, especially if I forget.

If anyone knows how to change the defaults to work each time automatically on start up. I'd much appreciate the advice.

Thanks